# Recibir datos en HEX en Arduino

Tags: arduino

Soy relativamente nuevo en Arduino y necesito recibir un dato en HEX y no siempre tiene el mismo largo.

```
11 4D 44 16 F0 60 00 28 28 28 81 12 12 12 38 01 60 00 00 34 AA 01 00 15 08 14 00 13 3A 1A 00 6A A6 4F C5 6F B8 DB C5 48 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0D 00 D5 03 EB FF 2A 00 B7 03 F0 FE 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8E 54 7E
```

Sí sé que empieza con 11 y termina con 7E

Luego debo parsearlo, sin embargo no sé como recibir el dato completo.

Por ejemplo en python lo puedo leer con binascii.unhexlify(data)

Gracias

Comment: Necesitas saber el tamaño de la información que vas a leer o tener algún dato que indique que se ha terminado de transmitir datos. De lo contrario es imposible. También, comparte tu código, es difícil poder ayudarte sin saber exactamente que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Acá está el código, logré obtener lo que necesito, aunque no creo que esté optimizado.

```
String readString;
String readStringRaw;
const byte numChars = 230;
char receivedChars[numChars];
int incomingByte = 0;

void loop() {

if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  int numBytes = Serial.available();
  for (int n = 0; n < numBytes; n++) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    readString = String(incomingByte, HEX);
    if (readString.length() == 1) {
      readStringRaw += "0" + readString;
    } else {
      readStringRaw += readString;
    }

  }
  if ((readStringRaw.startsWith("11")) && (readStringRaw.endsWith("7e"))) {
    
    int readStringRaw_len = readStringRaw.length();
    char readStringRaw_array[readStringRaw_len];
    readStringRaw.toCharArray(readStringRaw_array, readStringRaw_len);
    Serial.println(readStringRaw);
  }
  numBytes = 0;

}
```