# ¿Cómo comunicar un Arduino con Python en PC?

Tags: python, arduino, serialport, pyserial

Tengo una aplicación Python que corre en un PC y que necesita interactuar con un Arduino.

Toda la comunicación es iniciada por el PC; el Arduino sólo debe responder.

Las comunicaciones deben intercambiar textos y valores.

Ayuda, por favor, que nada me funciona.

Comment: es curioso como algunas preguntas las cierran por no coincidir con los "objetivos" de la comunidad y otras las responden como si fuese vital.

Comment: @tincopasan. ¿Notastes que es una pregunta-respuesta por la misma persona?

Comment: ¿notaste? que curioso el nivel de la respuesta a la pregunta para alguien que plantea que nada funciona, es más un tutorial encubierto que una pregunta y respuesta real.

Comment: @tincopasan. Exactamente. En lugar de tener que contestar una y otra vez la misma pregunta, hice esta pregunta-respuesta para que sirva de referencia,por ejemplo, para esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/522361/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-enviar-parte-de-un-dataframe-hacia-un-arduino.

Comment: O esta otra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492759/c%c3%b3mo-comparo-el-primer-caracter-de-una-linea-de-texto-enviada-por-serial-desde

Comment: Y esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489194/como-enviar-json-con-un-script-de-python-y-recibirlo-en-un-script-de-arduino

Comment: Y más: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489161/recibir-datos-en-hex-en-arduino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conceptos generales

Los valores numéricos deben ser representados como string para su traspaso y convertidos a numérico para usarlos en ambas plataformas. Es posible enviar datos binarios, si lo deseas, pero es complicarse la vida inútilmente.

Toda la comunicación Arduino-PC debe ser en "UTF-8", lo que requiere codificar/decodificar los datos en el lado PC para su envio/recepción.

Finalmente, siempre hay que enviar un '\n' al final del string, para marcar su término. Esto se requiere en ambos sentidos.

### Python

Usaremos `pyserial` para comunicarnos desde PC con el Arduino.

Primero debemos abrir la puerta serial que comunica con Arduino. Esto requiere identificar la serial y su velocidad, que debe ser compatibles con la contraparte:

```
 ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
```

En este caso, la puerta serial es `/dev/ttyUSB0`, lo que depende de la plataforma, y la velocidad es 9.600 bauds.

Para enviar un string, primero debes codificarlo en "UTF-8" usando `encode()`:

```
texto = "iniciar\n".encode("UTF-8") # Recuerda el \n al final.
ser.write(texto)
```

Para recibir una respuesta se usa `readline()`. Este método lee de la serial hasta detectar un `\n`. Si no lo encuentra, bloquea. La respuesta viene en UTF-8, y debe ser codificada para transformarla en un string Python:

```
 linea = ser.readline()
 respuesta = linea.decode()
 valor = int(respuesta)
```

Si la respuesta expresa un valor numérico, debe ser convertida apropiadamente, usando `int` o `float`.

### Arduino

Arduino requiere que la función `loop` ejecute en cada pasada en el mínimo tiempo posible, lo cual implica que la serial debe ser leída caracter a a caracter.

Si bien Arduino tiene un método `readString()` que retorna un dato tipo `String` desde la serial, no es recomendable usarlo. Este método bloquea hasta detectar un `\n` o dar *timeout*, lo que introduce todo tipo de errores aleatorios. Además, complica la codificación.

El patrón general es:

```
String buffer = "";

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()) {
    /*
     * Hay uno o más caracteres a leer en la serial.
     */
    int car = Serial.read();
    /*
     * Procesamos caracter a caracter por simplicidad.
     */
    if (car == '\n') {
      /*
       * El retorno de carro marca el fin de la entrada.
       */

      ... hacer alguna cosa con lo leido ...
 
      buffer = ""  // Limpiar el buffer una vez procesado.
      }
    } else {
      /*
       * Acumular los caracteres leídos.
       */
      buffer += (char) car;
    }
```

Primero, declaramos `buffer` como `String` fuera de `loop` para que conserve su valor durante la ejecución. En esta variable vamos acumulando los caracteres leidos hasta detectar el `\n` que marca el final.

Si hay caracteres por leer en la serial, los iremos leyendo y acumulando uno por uno, por rapidez y simplicidad.

Al detectar el `\n`, procesamos el buffer y lo limpiamos, para recibir el siguiente texto.

Todo lo recibido por Arduino es texto; si queremos considerarlo como valor, la clase `String` ofrece varias funciones como `toInt()`, `toFloat()`, etc.

Al enviar respuestas desde Arduino hacia el PC no necesitamos codificar nada (trabaja en ASCII, UTF-8 compatible) y el retorno de carro al final lo agrega automáticamente el método `println()`.

### Demo

**Arduino**

Este código Arduino lee de la serial. Los textos los devuelve transformados a mayúsculas; los valores los acumula y por cada uno recibido, retorna la suma acumulada.

[Por supuesto, no incluye manejo de errores.]

```
/*
 * Recibe textos y valores por la serial.
 * Responde convirtiendo textos a mayúsculas
 * y con la suma acumulada de los valores.
 */
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

String buffer = "";

void loop() {
  static float suma = 0.0;

  if (Serial.available()) {
    /*
     * Hay uno o más caracteres a leer en la serial.
     */
    int car = Serial.read();
    /*
     * Procesamos caracter a caracter por simplicidad.
     */
    if (car == '\n') {
      /*
       * El retorno de carro marca el fin de la entrada.
       */
      if (isDigit(buffer.charAt(0))) {
        suma += buffer.toFloat();
        Serial.println(suma);
      } else {       
        buffer.toUpperCase();
        Serial.println(buffer);
      }
      /*
       * Limpiar el buffer para recibir la siguiente entrada.
       */
      buffer = "";
    } else {
      /*
       * Acumular los caracteres leidos.
       */
      buffer += (char) car;
    }
  }
}
```

**Python**

Este código envía texto y valores al Arduino, recibe las respuestas y las muestra por consola.

[Por supuesto, no incluye manejo de errores.]

```
import serial

def encode_send(ser, texto):
     print(f"enviar: {texto}")
     enc = f"{texto}\n".encode("UTF-8")
     ser.write(enc)

def decode_response(ser):
     linea = ser.readline()
     respuesta = linea.decode()
     return respuesta

def conversar():
     ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
     valor1 = 125
     valor2 = 3.1415
     encode_send(ser, "Texto áéíóú")
     respuesta = decode_response(ser)
     print(f"recibido: {respuesta}")

     encode_send(ser, "valor1")
     decode_response(ser)
     encode_send(ser, f"{valor1}")
     respuesta = decode_response(ser)
     print(f"recibido: {respuesta}")

     encode_send(ser, "valor2")
     decode_response(ser)
     encode_send(ser, f"{valor2}")
     respuesta = decode_response(ser)
     print(f"recibido: {respuesta}")

     ser.close()
```

**Resultado**

```
enviar: Texto áéíóú
recibido: TEXTO áéíóú

enviar: valor1
enviar: 125
recibido: 125.00

enviar: valor2
enviar: 3.1415
recibido: 128.14


Process finished with exit code 0
```